# ASP.NET Entry Point?

Tags: asp.net

Just created a blank "ASP.NET Web Application". Where's the entry point?

I see "Default.aspx" which seems to be the default template that calls. "Site.Master" which I guess acts as a layout file. "Global.asax" that seems to provide some method stubs for event handling. And then "Web.config" which seems to have some site-specific settings such as a DB connection string, and some authentication stuff.

But no where do I see any "routes" or anything to indicate that "Default.aspx" should be called by default, or "Global.asax" should be used to handle events. Where's this stuff specified? Is it baked into the core of ASP? Can't I filter all the requests through one C# method and then delegate how I please? And return some sort of Http response?

Comment: Were you asking what is the first line of code that executes when an ASP.NET web application starts (takes its first request) or were you asking what code is hit when an arbitrary request is made to the site?

Comment: I *think* I wanted to know the first line of code that gets hit when a new request comes in. I may have forgotten that ASP.NET works differently than a PHP app in that ASP.NET is only booted once, whereas in PHP it runs everything on every request.

Comment: Right there are certain things that happen in an ASP.NET application only upon loading and then those things that happen on each request.  These links cover what happens in the page life cycle for ASP.NET Webforms applications and ASP.NET MVC applications respectively -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I think I wanted to know the first line of code that gets hit when a new request comes in.

The `HttpApplication` class contains the first line of code of your application. Its constructor is very much the entry point for your application. [From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx):

> After all core application objects have been initialized, the application is started by creating an instance of the HttpApplication class.

There are two canonical ways to write the first line of code that gets hit for a new request. Both involve creating a Global.asax file and handling its events.

> To handle application events or methods, you can create a file named Global.asax in the root directory of your application.

You will want to handle `Application_Start` and/or `Application_BeginRequest`.

- `Application_Start` is for code that gets hit on the very first request to the application. Each time we restart the application, the next request will enter here. This is **per application startup.**
- `Application_BeginRequest` is for code that gets hit on each request to the application. This is **per request.**

Of course, this all changes with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 7):

There's no notion of entry point. The way it works is that the user sends an HTTP request to an url and this url sends a response to the user. In the properties of the project you could configure which URL to launch in Visual Studio when you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> because by default it launches the file you are currently editing.

Also the web server has a notion of default document i.e. if you don't specify any page it will load the default documents in the order they are configured:

[image]

Comment: Good answer! I guess I have to ask another question though to get the *solution* I want.

Answer (score 3):

By default, ASP.NET just uses the physical file paths for determining which page to display. Default.aspx is the default either because it is the startup file of your project, or because it is mapped as the default document of your root folder in IIS.

You can optionally use the routing components added to the framework as part of ASP.NET MVC if you want custom routing. There's a guide on how to use this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

the entry is an IIS ISAPI extension that processes Asp.net requests.  If you want the routing you could use Asp.net mvc, or use an HttpModule to intercept and route the requests.

see more about Asp.net here. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20100620062357/https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp

Answer (score 2):

The file called by default is specified on the IIS, generally is default.aspx.

Comment: Okay....what about on the development server that I run through VS by pressing F5? Is there a project setting somewhere?

Comment: No, that server uses default.aspx as default pages (I think), but you can select start page on Visual Studio, by right click and select as Start page. That start page is the one loaded when you press F5