# Unhandled exception in ASP web.config connectionString setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, web-config, unhandled

I am running an `ASP` website and connect to a `SQL` database, very standard setup. The connection string details are held in the `<connectionStrings>` tag of the `web.config` file.

If the database username/password details are not correct, I get an `YSOD` unhandled exception notice. This is not at all surprising, but I would like to show a custom error page instead. However, I cannot seem to get the custom page to show using `<customErrors>` settings.

It seems an unhandled exception at the `web.config` level (for example the incorrect database connection string) means the application does not get as far as redirecting to the custom error page.

Any advice on how to handle this exception would be much appreciated. I understand if the exception happened on a particular page I can add a `try`/`catch` to catch it. I am not sure where/how I can handle this exception:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user xxxxx

Comment: Could you post your web.config where you define your custom error page redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Find place where this connection string is used and handle exception there.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find where it is being called/used. I have placed a try/catch in Global.asax Application_start function, which I thought was the first request to the application but even that does not seem to stop the exception. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264623/asp-net-entry-point